# Mocking an Interface Object of an Interface Method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have below interface method which I am mocking.

```
public interface IMessageBus : IDisposable
{
     IMessage CreateMessage<T>(T content);
}
```

Now I am able to Mock this interface for my Unit tests as below.

```
_messageBus = new Mock<IMessageBus>();
```

Now How do I setup the CreateMessage to return a particular Object that I want.

```
_messageBus.Setup(x => x.CreateMessage(It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(Mock.Of<IMessage>());
```

This just returns an empty object But I need a valid object to be returned. Something like this

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); // where obj is an Object.
```

Basically I need the above line to be returned when I call the

> CreateMessage

Method. How can we accomplish this?
**Note: I can do this by creating a `MockMessage` Class which implements the `IMessage` Interface and add required functionality.
But am wondering if we can do it without the explicit class definition.**

IMessage

```
public interface IMessage : IDisposable
    {
        string Id { get; }
        string CorrelationId { get; set; }
        string MessageContentType { get; }
        TimeSpan? TimeToLive { get; set; }
        AcknowledgementStatus AcknowledgementStatus { get; }
        IDictionary<string, object> CustomHeaders { get; }
        byte[] RawContent { get; }
        void Abandon();
        Task AbandonAsync();
        void Acknowledge();
        Task AcknowledgeAsync();
        IMessage Clone();
        T GetContent<T>();
        T GetContent<T>(IBinarySerializer serializer);
        IDictionary<string, object> GetMessageHeaders();
    }
```

Comment: You are actually really close, could you share `IMessage` interface?

Comment: Shared the interface.

Answer (score 1):

**`moq`** supports LINQ to Mocks, it is useful if you only want to setup returns.

*How you could use it?*

Actually you were really close to the solution, you could do for example:

```
_messageBus
    .Setup(x => x.CreateMessage(It.IsAny<object>()))
    .Returns(Mock.Of<IMessage>(m => m.Id == "MyId" && m.CorrelationId == "MyCorrelationId"));
```

if you dont want to use this feature, or you need something more complex, than use fluent api (`moq` takes care of the inner objects):

```
_messageBus
    .Setup(x => x.CreateMessage(It.IsAny<object>()).Id).Returns("MyId");
_messageBus
    .Setup(x => x.CreateMessage(It.IsAny<object>()).CorrelationId).Returns("MyCorrelationId ");
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be like so:

```
_messageBus.Setup(x => x.CreateMessage(It.IsAny<object>()))
    .Returns<object>(obj => 
    {
        var item = new Mock<IMessage>();
        // Setup properties/methods here
        item.Setup(i => i.Id).Returns(obj.Id);

        return item.Object;
    });
```